# UIScrollView doesn't scroll if started from pressing on textField

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, drag

I have UIScrollView with labels and textFields ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/eyaglu)).

I have calculated contentViewHeight based on number of views.

When started scrolling from image or label, scrollView scrolls perfect, but if I touch from textField and drag, scrollView didn't scroll or fire scrollViewDidScroll method.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When the textFieldShouldBeginEditing (_ :) option is trimmed, the total size of the View will be trimmed so you have those drawbacks.
You can define the scrollView in viewdidload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 570)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And using 'IQKeyboardManager' is highly recommended.